# How to convert uploaded via browser file to bytes?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, byte

I need to upload an image ([File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object) to a server as a bytes. Image is uploaded to a browser by a user through input field.

My problem is that an image must be converted to bytes and I can not find how it can be done in JS.

Below is the python code which works ok.

```
response_with_image = requests.get('some-url.png')
bytes_of_image = response_with_image.content # ->> b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x03R\x00\x00\x02\xbc\x08\x02\x00\x00\x00j}\x19\x16\x00\x00\x00\tpHYs\x00\x00\x0fa\x00\x00\x0fa\x01\xa8?\xa7i\x00\x00 \x00IDATx\x9c\xec\xbd\xbf\xcbuKr\x1eZ\xfd\xce\t,s\xb9\xfa\x17\x8ep\xa2@X\xe0\xbf`\x06\'g\xb8\xa9\xfe\x02i\x12#\xb8\xd1\x0c\x0e\'6\x9a\xe4\xfe0JfP$.\xf7"Pdt\x121\x03J\x84\xc0\xd8\xe0\t&\x11:\x18\x8c\x13e\x86\x19\x07:\xbbo\xf0~o\x9fZ\xf5<\xf5tu\xaf\xbd\xdf\xef\xdb3\xabh\x9a\xa7\xaa\xab\xaa{U\xf7\xea\xae\xd3\xeb\xdd\xdfi\xbdw\xbb\xe8\xa2\x8b.\xba\xe8\xa2\x8b.\xba\xe8\xd7\x9d^>\xf6......'

r = requests.put(url_to_upload_file, headers={"Content-Type": "image/png"}, data=bytes_of_image)
```

Currently the best I can achieve with JS is below - the code creates a file of incorrect size (90 KB instead of 66 KB) and of correct type. When I check uploaded file, browser does not recognize it as an image, obviously because I am uploading base64 instead of bytes.

```
const urlToUploadFile = 'url-provided-by-service'

const imageFile = files[0]
const reader = new FileReader()
reader.onloadend = function () {
    const result = reader.result // data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAsUAAAQJCAYAAAAuMXXtAAAgAElEQVR4nOzdfWxTd573/f6....

    await axios.put(
        urlToUploadFile,
        { data: result },
        { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'image/png' } }
    ).then(response => {
        console.log('response:', response)
    })

reader.readAsDataURL(imageFile)
```

I can not find how I can convert `imageFile` directly to bytes of `imageFile` -> base64 -> bytes.

Comment: Did you try using `readAsArrayBuffer` instead of `readAsDataURL`? That should do it. (There is also `readAsBinaryString` but it's better to use an array buffer if possible, axios should be fine with that.) Or did you get any errors with using an array buffer?

Comment: @CherryDT Yeap. With readAsArrayBuffer `reader.result` looks like: ArrayBuffer(67541) {} [[Int8Array]]: Int8Array(67541) [-119, 80, .... ] [[Uint8Array]]: Uint8Array(67541) [137, 80, .... ] and uploaded size is 11 B, when should be around 90 KB.

Comment: `reader.result` looks good to me. But I think you need to pass plainly `result` instead of `{ data: result }`. Because otherwise you are passing JSON with `result` stringified to a meaningless string like `[object ArrayBuffer]`.

Comment: Actually you may not even have to read the data first, please check what happens if you simply pass the `imageFile` itself, i.e. `axios.put(urlToUploadFile, imageFile, { headers: ... })`.

Comment: @CherryDT thanks, both ways (`reader.readAsArrayBuffer + result instead of { data: result }` AND simply `axios.put(urlToUploadFile, imageFile, { headers: ... })`) works. So stupid issue with `{data: result}` Please post the answer to let me accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an XY problem because you actually want to know how to pass the file directly into the request, and with the issue of how to convert base64 to bytes you are already down the wrong path. So it's best to take a step back, since there is a more straight-forward solution.

I see two problems here:

1. You are reading the file as data URL even though you need it in a raw form. My suggestion is to use [`readAsArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer) instead. But actually you don't have to read or convert the data at all - you could just pass the `imageFile` directly into `axios.put`. This should work because [`File` inherits from `Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) and axios accepts `Blob`s as body.
2. You are passing `{ data: result }` instead of just `result` as body argument to `axios.put`. The result is that axios will see an object with key `data` and some value and attempt to encode it, but actually you seem to be trying to directly upload the raw file (also according to your `Content-Type`). So, plainly using `axios.put(url, theData, { headers: ... })` instead of `axios.put(url, { data: theData }, { headers: ... })` should fix it.

By the way, instead of hardcoding the content type, you could also get it from `imageFile.type`.

---

Bottom line is that the following code should work:

```js
const urlToUploadFile = 'url-provided-by-service'

const imageFile = files[0]

await axios.put(
    urlToUploadFile,
    imageFile,
    { headers: { 'Content-Type': imageFile.type } }
).then(response => {
    console.log('response:', response)
})
```